# Specific fixed div inside a scroll content

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, fixed

I'm trying to make some magic here.

I have a master div, with limited width and height. This have a scroll xy. 
Inside, I need another object, like a bar, but this have to be fixed. and the content, have to scroll down and left.

Imagine a Table, with the thead fixed, but I can't use table, I must use LI elements, or else.

**CSS**

```
.c {clear: both;}
.thelimitedscrollediv {width:400px;  height: 200px; overflow: scroll;}
.fixedlargebar {position:fixed;  background:#ccc; width:900px; height: 20px}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="thelimitedscrollediv">

<div class="fixedlargebar">The fixed bar. This needs to scroll X</div>
<br class="c" />
And here the normal content. This have to scroll x y. 
</div><!-- @end of limitedscrollediv -->
```

Anyone know can I fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel, this worked, but, I need to make the bar fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement in code:

```
<div class="fixedlargebar">The fixed bar. This needs to scroll X</div>
```

W3C specs:

> The box's position is calculated according to the 'absolute' model,
>   but in addition, the box is fixed with respect to some reference. As
>   with the 'absolute' model, the box's margins do not collapse with any
>   other margins. In the case of handheld, projection, screen, tty, and
>   tv media types, **the box is fixed with respect to the viewport and does
>   not move when scrolled**. [Full read](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position)

The simple answer is you can't achieve what you want without javascript.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I guess this will fix the problem https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed